# 2 values in an Array to 2 columns in my DataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Apache Spark in Java, I have:

```
root
 |-- datasetid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fields: struct (nullable = true)
...
 |    |-- latlon: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

This is based on this JSON fragment:

```
"fields":{
  "latlon":[
    35.9543748,
    -78.9944911
  ],
```

I was trying to extract the data to a column using:

```
df = df.withColumn("lat", df.col("fields.latlon[0]"));
df = df.withColumn("lon", df.col("fields.latlon[1]"));
```

(I hope you appreciate the neatness of the syntax). However, I must admit it does not really work:

```
No such struct field latlon[1] in
```

I tried a few other things without much luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code

```
df.withColumn("lat", $"fields.latlon".getItem(0))
  .withColumn("lon", $"fields.latlon".getItem(1))
```

Use sql

```
df.registerTempTable("geo")
latlon = sqlContext.sql("select fields.latlon[0] as lat, fields.latlon[1] as lon from geo")
```

Comment: Awesome @Rockie! I just changed the notation to be more Java and less Scala using the static method col(). Thanks for your help!